# How to order the rows information of a data set with two criteria

Tags: r, rows

I have a data set containing information about academic degrees per year, like this:

```
Year1  Deg_Year1  Year2  Deg_Year2  Year3  Deg_Year3  Year4  Deg_Year4  Year5  Deg_Year5   
2001   College    2004   Master      NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2004   College    2004   Master      2010    PHD       NA       NA        NA       NA 
2006   Master     2006   College     NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2016   Master     NA     NA          NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2002   Master     2003   Master      2004    College   2004     Master    NA       NA  
2014   Master     2017   PHD         NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
```

I want to obtain a data frame that contains the year and the highest academic degree obtained just before 2015, like this:

```
YearX   Highest_Degree
2004    Master
2010    PHD
2006    Master
NA      NA
2004    Master
2014    Master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, what a terrible data format. We add an ID column, clean it up, and then we can get what you want in a few lines.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
# create ID column
mutate(dd, id = 1:n()) %>%
# convert degree and year columns to long format
gather(dd, key = "degkey", value = "degree", starts_with("Deg")) %>%
    gather(key = "yearkey", value = "year", starts_with("Year")) %>%
  # pull the numbers into an index
  mutate(yr_index = str_extract(yearkey, "[0-9]+"),
             deg_index = str_extract(degkey, "[0-9]+")) %>%
    # get rid of junk and filter to the years you want
    filter(yr_index == deg_index, year < 2015) %>%
    # order by descending index
    arrange(desc(yr_index)) %>%
    # keep relevant columns
    select(id, degree, year) %>%
    # for each ID, keep the top row
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice(1) %>% 
    # join back to the original to complete any lost IDs
    right_join(select(dd, id))

# Joining, by = "id"
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   id [?]
#      id  degree  year
#   <int>   <chr> <int>
# 1     1  Master  2004
# 2     2     PHD  2010
# 3     3 College  2006
# 4     4    <NA>    NA
# 5     5  Master  2004
# 6     6  Master  2014
# Warning message:
# attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped
```

---

Using this data:

```
dd = read.table(text = "Year1  Deg_Year1  Year2  Deg_Year2  Year3  Deg_Year3  Year4  Deg_Year4  Year5  Deg_Year5   
2001   College    2004   Master      NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2004   College    2004   Master      2010    PHD       NA       NA        NA       NA 
2006   Master     2006   College     NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2016   Master     NA     NA          NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA
2002   Master     2003   Master      2004    College   2004     Master    NA       NA  
2014   Master     2017   PHD         NA      NA        NA       NA        NA       NA",
                                header = T)
```